# Нужна ли запятая после слова?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в приведённом предложении запятая после слова "единение"?

**Итак, мы убедились, что патриотизм, **а в особенности единение** — основная идея "Слова о полку Игореве".**

Answer (score 1):

**Запятая нужна:** *Итак, мы убедились, что патриотизм, **а в особенности единение**, — основная идея "Слова о полку Игореве".*

1. Оборот обособляется:       **[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_94)**

Если слова «в особенности» входят в состав **присоединительного оборота,** содержащего дополнительные замечания или разъяснения, то они обособляются вместе со всем оборотом.

Постановка тире и запятой — **независимая**.

2. Запятая нужна еще и для правильного понимания **грамматики** предложения (иначе оборот можно отнести ко второй части предложения).